# executing programs from command prompt

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, command, prompt

I am having trouble with executing my executable file by executing my program from the location of the program. I am using eclipse, and when I paste the location of my executable file from debug in eclipse, onto the command prompt my program works perfectly. However when I try to execute my program from the location of the debug, my program is altered, any help please?

Comment: Altered? In what way? Is it hijacked by terrorists or what?

Comment: it's not as it should be

Comment: When you execute the program, what does it do? not not do?  Still do not get "altered"

Comment: it doesn't work the same way as it worked when I used it by pasting location. Like exiting the command prompt at a certain point, and it never did before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After it begins to execute, is your program using relative paths to input files that might be different?

Are you an administrator on the computer and/or running eclipse as administrator? You could try running the command prompt as administrator to confirm that it isn't a permissions issue.

Comment: I'm sorry "relative paths to input files that might be different?" not that technical.

Comment: I tried it, not a permissions issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't work it in the debug. Because the program is working in the normal directory. Simply work in normal directory and its fine.

Your question does not seem like a real question.

Comment: When I run by pasting from eclipse, I'm still using the debug location though right ? and I need to run from debug, as I need this to be presented

Comment: No when you run the program, you are using the directory that .exe exits. Debug directory is using from the program for debug like it said. You can not run anything in debug directory. It is nor needed neither logical.

Comment: So from where should I run the program then from my files?

Comment: Whereever you want. Problem is you are not clearly declared your expectations. So i can not understand properly. But i can say that you can run it through the cmd or eclipse. Eclipse going to do it automatically and cmd needs to directory location. If its still not clear for you, try to open your question more. Its not clear yet.

Comment: I need to be able to run my program from the files I have in my project folder which includes my .c files, debug and settings, the folder which eclipse makes to store them in. When I copy the Debug executable path from eclipse and pate in cmd it works. What I was trying to do is opening my Debug folder from the folder eclipse creates, and then run the Application found in the Debug Folder, which opens up my cmd and runs my program, however it seems that not everything in my program works this way, could it be that it's an old version of the program ?

Comment: Mate, there must be 2 exe file there. One near the .c and other one in debug. Debug is designed for debug (it should not work for normal exe). Other one near .c file, is for run. Maybe your exe was deleted by you or somehow or you are looking at wrong directory.

Comment: I guess it was deleted then I don't have another file, would the release folder work?

Comment: Yes it must be in release or near .c around. Im pretty sure its not in the debug folder. Try to copy the debug and run it in the release folder. Worth to try :)